# What do these 2 ASP.NET rewrite rules do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET MVC application (it's quite old). There is an rewrite.config file with 2 enabled rewrite rules.

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I think the 2nd rule converts http://www.example.com/blah to https://www.example.com/blah

But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule if the `HTTP_HOST` is NOT [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it will do a 301 redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with the rest of the url.

So, for example if you had an incoming URL of `example.com/my-page` it would do a 301 redirect to http://www.example.com/my-page

The key difference here is that `negate="true"` is essentially the equivalent of "Not" in logical processing.  So the conditional there is if the host is NOT `www.example.com` then do this.

As a side note, If leaving this in place to avoid a double redirect I would change the canonical redirect rule to redirect to https as otherwise it will do two successive redirects which is unnecessary.